# Dragable only one of plot series

Tags: jqplot

I have 3 series on my chart. Is it possible to give user only one serie to modify (as dragable line) whilst other can't be modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally undocumented, but browsing the source for the dragable plugin it is as simple as setting the isDragable property for that series to false.

```
series:[{},{isDragable:false}] //set the second series to be undraggable.
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/YgkqU/1/).

Comment: It's included only in one [paragraph](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/optionsTutorial-txt.html) (at the bottom)